# If $X_n \overset{p}{\to} X$, want to show that $f(X_n) \overset{p}{\to} f(X)$ for $f$ a continuous bounded function.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am trying to show that if $X_n \overset{p}{\to} X$, then $f(X_n) \overset{p}{\to} f(X)$ for $f$ a continuous bounded function.

My proof:

Since $f$ is continuous, we have that for all $\omega \in \Omega$ and $\epsilon, \delta \geq 0$, there is an $n(\omega) >0$ such that

$$
\mid X_n(\omega)-X(\omega)\mid < \delta \implies \mid f(X_n(\omega)) - f(X(\omega))\mid < \epsilon
$$
or 
$$
\mid f(X_n(\omega)) - f(X(\omega))\mid \geq \epsilon \implies \mid X_n(\omega)-X(\omega)\mid \geq \delta
$$

Hence, if we set $N = max(n(\omega))$, we have that for all $n >N$,

$$
\{\omega : \mid f(X_n(\omega)) - f(X(\omega))\mid \geq \epsilon\} \subset \{\omega : \mid X_n(\omega)-X(\omega)\mid \geq \delta\}
$$

Therefore,

$$
P\{\omega : \mid f(X_n(\omega)) - f(X(\omega))\mid \geq \epsilon\} \subset P\{\omega : \mid X_n(\omega)-X(\omega)\mid \geq \delta\} \to 0
$$

The part I am very shaky about is the second to last line, I was able to get that by deducing the result, but I am unsure why

$$\mid f(X_n(\omega)) - f(X(\omega))\mid \geq \epsilon \implies \mid X_n(\omega)-X(\omega)\mid \geq \delta
$$

implies that

$$ \{\omega : \mid f(X_n(\omega)) - f(X(\omega))\mid \geq \epsilon\} \subset \{\omega : \mid X_n(\omega)-X(\omega)\mid \geq \delta\}$$.

In general, if $A$ implies $B$, would that mean $A \subset B$? Thanks!

Comment: The first epsilon-delta property characterizes uniform continuity, not continuity, hence more work is needed here. Hint: Any continuous function is indeed uniformly continuous on compact sets.

Comment: Another approach is to use the following criterion: $\xi_n\overset{P}{\longrightarrow} \xi$ iff any subsequence of $\{\xi_n\}$ contains a subsequence converging to $\xi$ *almost surely*. Then the statement becomes quite obvious. But I don't advertise this approach as it uses some deeper results